# How to update a column to latest data while referencing other columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I am very new to SQL and have been given a dataset to clean as part of my internship.

I reproduce part of the table below:

```
Period    Policy No  Client No  Premium
----------------------------------------
2021-01   88888888   56785678   $1234.00
2019-07   88888888   89237427   $4567.01
2018-05   12345678   11111111   $2322.99
2019-10   12345678   22222222   $4321.12

etc..
```

Basically, I need to create a new column, say, `New Client No` to reflect the latest client number, which is determined based on the `Period` column, for each `Policy No`. For example, the table above should look like the following:

```
Period    Policy No  Client No  New Client No  Premium
------------------------------------------------------
2021-01   88888888   56785678   56785678       $1234.00
2019-07   88888888   89237427   56785678       $4567.01
2018-05   12345678   11111111   22222222       $2322.99
2019-10   12345678   22222222   22222222       $4321.12

etc..
```

In other words, each policy number must correspond to only one client number and this client number must be the latest one, as determined by the period. Note that I cannot simply combine rows as I have many more columns, such as `Premium`, which contain data that I cannot "collate".

Is there an easy way to do this? I am certainly not looking forward to hard-coding them, as I have to rectify about 60 policy numbers. The dataset is also huge, with millions of rows, if that is relevant.

I have tried many things, such as playing around with `joins`, `row_number() over (partition by)` etc, but none seem to do the trick, or perhaps it is because my logic is not quite right and I also do not fully understand how they work.

As mentioned, I am very new to SQL, so any intuitive suggestions will be greatly appreciated! :)

P.S. I also heard that syntax sometimes differs based on the database system one uses, so for what it is worth, I am using Microsoft SQL Server!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a query using `first_value`:

```
select t.*,
       first_value(client_no) over (partition by policy_no order by period desc) as most_recent_client_no
from t;
```

If you want to actually change the data (which seems dangerous because it is so easy to get the most recent value), you can use:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             first_value(client_no) over (partition by policy_no order by period desc) as most_recent_client_no
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set client_no = most_recent_client_no
    where client_no <> most_recent_client_no;
```

Comment: Hi! Actually I was editing my post halfway but you already posted an answer! Could you kindly see my edited post? I do not intend to change the original column, as you rightly pointed out that that is dangerous. Rather, I would like to create a new column, say, `New Client No`, to the right of `Client No`, which reflects the correct client number for each policy number. Then, for the rows which do not have a change in client number, the `New Client No` column would be the same as the `Client No` column. How can I do this?

Comment: @EthanMark . . . The first query generates the new column.

Comment: Right... Sorry it is very late for me right now so my brain refuses to function. Thank you for your help! I must say I did not know of the existence of the `FIRST_VALUE` function - it really simplifies a lot of coding!